# Exporting/Importing Keras Model to Tensorflow fails when using multi_gpu_model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, export, keras

I'm currently struggeling with importing my exported Keras model into Tensorflow. The code worked fine with a sequential model. I was able to train the model in python and then import it into my c++ application. Since I needed more ressources I decided to distribute the model onto several GPUs. Afterwards I was not able to import the model.

This is how I created my model before:

```
  input_img = Input(shape=(imgDim, imgDim, 1)) 

  # add several layers to net

  model = Model(input_img, net)

  model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
                loss='binary_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

  model.fit(x_train, y_train,
            epochs=100,
            batch_size=100,
            shuffle=True,
            validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

  saveKerasModelAsProtobuf(model, outpath)
```

This is how I export my model:

```
def saveKerasModelAsProtobuf(model, outputPath):
  signature = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.predict_signature_def(
    inputs={'image': model.input}, outputs={'scores': model.output})

  builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(outputPath)                                                                    
  builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
    sess=keras.backend.get_session(),                                                                                                                    
    tags=[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],                                                                                             
    signature_def_map={
      tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:
      signature    
    }
  )         
  builder.save()

  return
```

This is how I changed the code to run on multiple GPUs:

```
  input_img = Input(shape=(imgDim, imgDim, 1)) 

  # add several layers to net

  model = Model(input_img, net)

  parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=4)

  parallel_model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
                loss='binary_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

  parallel_model.fit(x_train, y_train,
            epochs=100,
            batch_size=100,
            shuffle=True,
            validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

  # export model rather than parallel_model:
  saveKerasModelAsProtobuf(model, outpath)
```

When I try to import the model in C++ on a single GPU machine I get the following error, indicating that it's not actually the sequential model (as I would expect) but the parallel_model:

```
Cannot assign a device for operation 'replica_3/lambda_4/Shape': Operation was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:3 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 ]. Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device.
 [[Node: replica_3/lambda_4/Shape = Shape[T=DT_FLOAT, _output_shapes=[[4]], out_type=DT_INT32, _device="/device:GPU:3"](input_1)]]
```

From what I read, they should share the same weights, but not the internal structure. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better/more generic way to export the model?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought about saving weights only and load it to a model replica on a CPU? Your problem seems to be caused by lack of GPU.

Comment: Thanks @MarcinMożejko. Training and Applying the model happen on different machines. The training machine has 4 dedicated GPUs, whereas the other machine has only one. That's why the error occurs. I guess if the machine had 4 GPUs it would run, but... why is it the parallel_model which is trained on the 4 GPUs and not 'model' which is what I'm exporting: `saveKerasModelAsProtobuf(model, outpath)` ?

Comment: Probably because the computational graph is connected to parts computed on different devices. And that's why inferred graph took also parts from other devices. I'd personally go for saving weights.

Comment: So was my advice correct?